# SQL Injection "Error 1 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

Tags: sql-injection, mysql

I am injecting:

```
-35' and updatexml(null,concat(0x3a,(0x0a,(select database()))),null)-- -
```

and I am receiving:

```
Error 1 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Any idea how to fix this?
I am trying to get the database type.

References:

- http://www.securityidiots.com/Web-Pentest/SQL-Injection/Error-Based-Injection-Subquery-Injection.html
- http://securityidiots.com/Web-Pentest/SQL-Injection/XPATH-Error-Based-Injection-UpdateXML.html

Comment: I'm not an expert in SQLi but maybe the and condition causes the issue?..

Comment: Questions about SQL syntax are off topic on Security SE.

Answer (score 0):

Your injection assumes that the injection point is in the where clause, but the error implies that the injection point is in the select clause. You should try some strings that play with the input to determine the injection point.

For example you could try:

```
 -35' from dual-- -
```

to see if this results in a valid query.